# Bigcommerce API Get Store Resource w/PHP

Tags: bigcommerce

I am trying to get to the store resource (name, domain, etc) of the Bigcommerce API using PHP.

I can get to product, category, time, and other resources, I just cannot figure out how to get to these with PHP.

I have tried using Bigcommerce::getStore() and several variations with no luck.

Comment: I was informed that I could use the following: `$var = Bigcommerce::getResource('/store', 'address');` but it did not work for me to grab the 'name' or 'domain' variables.

Comment: I wound up using cURL to grab the store json object and the json_decode php function to get the needed items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has not been implemented in the PHP SDK yet, from the looks of it. 
Use this branch https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-php/pull/62

The code is

```
$store = Bigcommerce::getStore();
print_r($store);
```